# Trying to attach a handler to linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello I am trying to get this Pager working. I am having some trouble adding the event handler to pagerCommand event. What am i doing wrong? I can attach the handler to the dropdown with no problem, but the link is having an issue. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

```
   Public Class DataPagerDDL
    Inherits DataPager

    Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.CreateDefaultPagerFields()
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CreateDefaultPagerFields()

        'add custom template
        Dim templateField As TemplatePagerField = New TemplatePagerField
        templateField.PagerTemplate = New CustomTemplate
        'add previous/next page template
        Fields.Add(templateField)
    End Sub

    Public Sub cmbPage_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim cmbPage As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
        SetPageProperties((cmbPage.SelectedIndex * MaximumRows), MaximumRows, True)
    End Sub
    Public Sub cmb_PagerCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataPagerCommandEventArgs)
        ' Check which button raised the event
        Select Case e.CommandName

            Case "Next"
                Dim newIndex As Integer = e.Item.Pager.StartRowIndex + e.Item.Pager.PageSize
                If newIndex <= e.TotalRowCount Then
                    e.NewStartRowIndex = newIndex
                    e.NewMaximumRows = e.Item.Pager.MaximumRows
                End If

            Case "Previous"
                e.NewStartRowIndex = e.Item.Pager.StartRowIndex - e.Item.Pager.PageSize
                e.NewMaximumRows = e.Item.Pager.MaximumRows

            Case "First"
                e.NewStartRowIndex = 0
                e.NewMaximumRows = e.Item.Pager.MaximumRows
            Case "Last"
                Dim newIndex As Integer = e.Item.Pager.StartRowIndex + e.Item.Pager.PageSize
                If newIndex <= e.TotalRowCount Then
                    e.NewStartRowIndex = newIndex
                    e.NewMaximumRows = e.Item.Pager.MaximumRows
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class CustomTemplate
    Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate
    Dim PageCount As Integer
    Dim CurrentPage As Integer
    Dim PageSize As Integer
    Dim TotalRowCount As Integer
    Dim MaximumRows As Integer
    Dim StartRowIndex As Integer

    Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As System.Web.UI.Control) Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn

        Dim caller As DataPagerFieldItem = CType(container, DataPagerFieldItem)
        Dim pager As DataPagerDDL = CType(caller.Parent, DataPagerDDL)
        PageSize = pager.PageSize
        TotalRowCount = pager.TotalRowCount
        MaximumRows = pager.MaximumRows
        PageCount = (TotalRowCount / MaximumRows)
        If ((pager.TotalRowCount Mod pager.MaximumRows) > 0) Then
            PageCount = (PageCount + 1)
        End If

        Dim link As LinkButton = New LinkButton
        'first Link
        link.Text = "<< First "
        link.CommandName = "Page"
        link.CommandArgument = "First"
        link.ID = "lnkFirst"
        link.Enabled = StartRowIndex > 0
        container.Controls.Add(link)

        'prev link
        link = New LinkButton
        link.Text = "< Prev "
        link.CommandName = "Page"
        link.CommandArgument = "Previous"
        link.ID = "lnkPrev"
        link.Enabled = StartRowIndex > 0
        container.Controls.Add(link)

        CurrentPage = ((StartRowIndex / MaximumRows) + 1)
        Dim cmbPage As DropDownList = New DropDownList
        cmbPage.ID = "cmbPage"
        cmbPage.AutoPostBack = True
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i <= PageCount)
            Dim item As ListItem = New ListItem(i.ToString, i.ToString)
            If (i = CurrentPage) Then
                item.Selected = True
            End If

            cmbPage.Items.Add(item)
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
        AddHandler cmbPage.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf pager.cmbPage_SelectedIndexChanged
        'add nav buttons

        ' we just add a Label with 'Page ' Text
        container.Controls.Add(PageOf())

        ' our DropDownList control here.
        container.Controls.Add(cmbPage)


        ' and our Total number of Pages
        container.Controls.Add(PageTotal())

        'next link
        link = New LinkButton
        link.Text = "Next > "
        link.CommandName = "Page"
        link.CommandArgument = "Next"
        link.ID = "lnkNext"
        link.Enabled = StartRowIndex + PageSize < TotalRowCount
        container.Controls.Add(link)

        'last link
        link = New LinkButton
        link.Text = "Last >> "
        link.CommandName = "Page"
        link.CommandArgument = "Last"
        link.ID = "lnkLast"
        link.Enabled = StartRowIndex + PageSize < TotalRowCount

        'Problem line
         AddHandler pager.cmb_PagerCommand, New EventHandler(AddressOf pager.cmb_PagerCommand)

        container.Controls.Add(link)

        container.Controls.Add(PageInfo(TotalRowCount))

    End Sub
    Private Function PageOf() As Label
        ' it is just a label
        Dim lbl As New Label()
        lbl.Text = "&nbsp;Page "
        Return lbl
    End Function

    Private Function PageTotal() As Label
        ' a label of GridView's Page Count
        Dim lbl As New Label()
        lbl.Text = String.Format(" of {0} ", PageCount)
        Return lbl
    End Function

    Private Function PageInfo(ByVal rowCount As Integer) As Label
        ' create a label that will display the current Record you're in
        Dim label As New Label()
        Dim currentPageFirstRow As Integer = ((CurrentPage * PageSize) + 1)
        Dim currentPageLastRow As Integer = 0
        Dim lastPageRemainder As Integer = rowCount Mod PageSize
        currentPageLastRow = IIf((PageCount = CurrentPage + 1), (currentPageFirstRow + lastPageRemainder - 1), (currentPageFirstRow + PageSize - 1))
        label.Text = [String].Format("Record {0} to {1} of {2}", currentPageFirstRow, currentPageLastRow, rowCount)
        Return label
    End Function

End Class
```

[DataPager.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Gdf.png) 
This is what I have for my gridview, I am trying to replicate the functionality in a free standing pager. A little stumped at the moment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing the following line of code

```
 AddHandler pager.cmb_PagerCommand, New EventHandler(AddressOf pager.cmb_PagerCommand)
```

with

```
AddHandler link.Command, AddressOf pager.cmb_PagerCommand
```

Comment: When I do that, it generates a different error. Event handler can't be converted to command event hamdler

Comment: You can fix that error by updating code as AddHandler link.Command, New CommandEventHandler(AddressOf pager.cmb.PagerCommand)

Comment: After following @Mohsin Mehmood's code fix, I have a control that compiles. Now when I run the application I get this error, 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataPagerCommandEventArgs'. There must be a way to to convert command eventArgs to DataPager Command Eventargs

Comment: According to Microsoft regarding the DataPagerComand there is no handler for it, as it uses a delagate. How do you use a delagate to invoke the commands?